# Senior friendly MP3 player with speaker

Tags: speakers, portable, mp3-player

Looking for an MP3 player for a senior.

The **ONLY** use case is "turn on player on max volume, play 100% of mp3s in storage in default sequence until battery dies or turned off".

**Features, in order of importance:**

- **Built-in speaker with reasonable volume (absolutely required).**
- At least 4GB memory. Support for SD Cards preferred as nice to have.
- Decent play time (at least 4-6 hours per charge/battery). Does not matter if it requires recharging or changing batteries, but cannot be dependent on wall power fulltime.
- EASY controls. Preferably simple, big buttons, does not require complex manipulation like "press and hold for 2 seconds" to power up.
- Cost. Should be less than $50 and available in USA for shipping.

**Do not care about:**

- Specifics of power. Can be batteries or rechargeable. As long as doesn't require wall power during use.
- Capacity/storage beyond 4GB. Nice to have but not needed.
- Screen is not required.
- Bluetooth not required (actually prefer no BT as it drains battery)
- Complex functionality. See "Use Case" above. No need to skip, random, forward, show playlist, have directories/playlists, configuration, etc...

What have I Tried:

- Sansa Shaker. Used to be cheap but couldn't find for less than $100 on Amazon lately.

Answer (score 2):

There are not too many that fit the description. Here is one:

> C18 is an high-performance MP3 player with 1.8 inches Screen which can show the relevant information. Built-in 8GB memory capacity ensures you to download your favorite songs freely. And, it supports many audio formats such as, MP3, WMA, AAC, APE, FLAC, WAV, etc and supports TF Card (Up to 128G).

- Memory: 8GB
- Charge Port: Micro USB
- Music Playing Time: about 10 hours (depends on music volume)
- Standby Time: about 30 hours
- Built-in loud speaker enables you to enjoy music without headphones, convenient to use.
- US Warehouse

  - USPS 3-6 business days
  - UPS  2-5 business days

**References**

- [C18 MP3 Player HiFi Metal Music Player 8GB - Tomtop](https://www.tomtop.com/p-v3112s.html)